# How to get rid of warnings with MEM and SSD tiers

Tags: memory, alluxio

I have two tiers: MEM+SSD. The MEM layer is almost always at 90% full and sometimes the SSD tier is also full.
Now this (kind of) message is sometimes spamming my log:

```
2022-06-14 07:11:43,607 WARN  TieredBlockStore - Target tier: BlockStoreLocation{TierAlias=MEM, DirIndex=0, MediumType=MEM} has no available space to store 67108864 bytes for session: -4254416005596851101
2022-06-14 07:11:43,607 WARN  BlockTransferExecutor - Transfer-order: BlockTransferInfo{TransferType=SWAP, SrcBlockId=36401609441282, DstBlockId=36240078405636, SrcLocation=BlockStoreLocation{TierAlias=MEM, DirIndex=0, MediumType=MEM}, DstLocation=BlockStoreLocation{TierAlias=SSD, DirIndex=0, MediumType=SSD}} failed. alluxio.exception.WorkerOutOfSpaceException: Failed to find space in BlockStoreLocation{TierAlias=MEM, DirIndex=0, MediumType=MEM} to move blockId 36240078405636 
2022-06-14 07:11:43,607 WARN  AlignTask - Insufficient space for worker swap space, swap restore task called.
```

Is my setup flawed? What can I do to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

looks like alluxio worker is trying to move/swap some blocks but there is no enough space to finish the operation. I guess it might be caused by both the ssd and mem tiers are full. Have you tried this property? `alluxio.worker.tieredstore.free.ahead.bytes` This can help us determine whether the swap failed due to insufficient storage space.